# Как программно снять флаг "Только для чтения" с папки в Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, readonly, mql

сообщество Stack Overflow!

Мне нужно программно снять атрибут "Только для чтения" с определенной папки в моей системе Windows. У меня есть программа, которая пытается записать данные в эту папку, но она не может это сделать, потому что папка помечена как "Только для чтения".

Как я могу сделать это с помощью кода? Ничего не помогает, перепробовал множество решений: cmd, права администратора, безопасность, все применяется к папкам и файлам но ничего не меняется, в свойствах "Только для чтения".

Спасибо!

Comment: Какой ЯП? Меток нет.

Comment: Программа на языке MQL4

Comment: Внезапно. Напрямую никак, только через `WinExec()`.